# Make UIPopoverController for IPad equal to screen size

Tags: iphone, ipad, uipopovercontroller

I want to make size of `UIPopoverController` equal to that of IPad screen for both orientations. How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

```
CGRect popoverRect = [self.view convertRect:[btn frame] 
                                   fromView:[btn superview]];

popoverRect.size.width = self.view.frame.size.width; 
popoverRect.origin.x  = popoverRect.origin.x+150; 
popoverRect.size.height = self.view.frame.size.width;
[self.popoverController 
 presentPopoverFromRect:popoverRect 
 inView:self.view 
 permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionLeft
 animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
[super viewDidAppear:animated];
self.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(width,height);}
```

this is set in view which you have to set in popover controller